# Are there any scenarios I need both 32-bit and 64-bit IFilter on the same machine?

Tags: windows, sharepoint, 64-bit, search, search-server

Since 32-bit applications run mostly fine on 64-bit Windows are there any scenarious where I will have 32-bit Microsoft Search IFilter consumers on a 64-bit machine? Can I just install the 64-bit version or do I need both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that you only need the 64bit version on the 64bit platform.

Looking at it from another perspective, why would you run 32bit SharePoint on a 64bit OS?
(Other than some strange compatibility issue)
SharePoint loves memory, the more the merrier, and 64bit lays the ground for that.